# Conditional fields based on select value in SiteOrigin Page Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events, siteorigin

I'm trying to integrate Page Builder by SiteOrigin into my plugin. I've added some custom fields under the row styles via the `siteorigin_panels_row_style_fields`filter found [here](https://siteorigin.com/docs/page-builder/hooks/custom-row-settings/). One of the custom fields is a select. I would like fields to either be hidden or displayed when the select is at a certain value. I've enqueued the Javascript to Page Builder using the `siteorigin_panel_enqueue_admin_scripts`action as per [the documentation](https://siteorigin.com/docs/page-builder/widget-compatibility/), and have even added the `panelsopen` event with some test code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('panelsopen', function(e) {
    $('select[name="style[test_field]"]').bind('change', function (e) {
      if( $(this).val() == 'option1' ) {
        $('input[name="style[second_field]').hide(500);
        $('input[name="style[third_field]').show(500);
      } else {
        $('input[name="style[second_field]').show(500);
        $('input[name="style[third_field]').hide(500);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However, this does not seem to be working. Any help or ideas how I could solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I figured this out by using the `ajaxComplete()` function in jQuery. This is how it works:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

    $('select[name="style[test_field]"]').bind('change', function (e) {
      if( $(this).val() == 'option1' ) {
        $('input[name="style[second_field]').hide(500);
        $('input[name="style[third_field]').show(500);
      } else {
        $('input[name="style[second_field]').show(500);
        $('input[name="style[third_field]').hide(500);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to achieve something similar.